# Django drf-yasg API versions switch from drop down

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, versioning, drf-yasg

Is there a way to show available API versions in drop down using drf_yasg without overwriting the template?

I checked their docs but seems like i have to use versionized URL to see different version of API, or i can show all API version URLs on same page. But I want to have a drop down to show only selected version paths.